# Problema fechas en jquery y código php

Tags: php, jquery

Tengo una función ready de jquey para ponerle un valor desde php a un campo fecha que tengo en un formulario. Está en el mismo formato y parece que lo coge bien, porque he puesto un alert que muestra la fecha y justo detrás se ve un poco que le pone los valores, pero el problema es que al darle a aceptar me lo vuelve a poner en blanco. Puede ser cosa del DOM si ya está cargada la página?

El código:

```
            function siFechaSeleccionada() {

        <?php

            if ($fechahoy!=null) {// la primera vez que entra
        ?>
                $('#selfecha').show();
                $('#selrango1').hide();
                $('#selrango2').hide();
                $('#nombredesde').hide();
                $('#nombrehasta').hide();
                //fecha hoy
                $('#selfecha').val("<?php echo $fechahoy;?>");
                alert("<?php echo $fechahoy;?>");

        <?php
        }
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando le doy a aceptar ya ha perdido el valor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuando se ejecuta esa función?

Comment: Al entrar en esa página, está puesto en una función ready

Comment: ¿Cuando le das a aceptar te refieres al botón verde o al aceptar del alert? Es probable que la página se recargue al pulsar aceptar (en el caso del botón verde). Yo usaría Ajax para esto, impidiendo de ese modo manipular variables del servidor directamente en este archivo, además para actualizar cualquier cosa del servidor habría que recargar la página, mientras que con Ajax no.

Comment: Me intento explicar mejor. Al entrar a ésta página cargo la fecha de hoy y unas tablas con registros, donde elimina registros de una o varias fechas que seleccione. Borra los registros que haya seleccionado de esa o esas fechas seleccionadas y vuelve a la misma página, mi idea era que se quedaran esas fechas que seleccionó en el date. Supongo que si lo cargo con Ajax la fecha y el compuesto(Selecciona tambien de un select) al volver a la página con php esos valores los pierda, o tenga que hacer todo con Ajax,no?

Comment: Cedano, cuando se borra del date es al darle al botón aceptar del alert que tengo justo encima de la línea donde asigno al date el valor. Yo supongo que es tema de servidor y cliente. puede ser? Al verde si cuento con que se borra, ya que vuelve a recargar la página, pero guardo los valores en variables y los devuelvo para ponerlos. pero como ves, no funciona, y me dá que es por eso, ya que al entrar lo pone y se borra al aceptar el alert

Comment: Ajax funciona precisamente al revés de como crees. Cuando usas Ajax la página no se recarga, porque Ajax usa otro archivo (en el servidor) que no es el actual el cual sirve como pasarela entre el cliente (página actual) y el servidor. Es ese otro archivo el que se encarga de traer y llevar datos al servidor, de modo que mientras esa ida y vuelta de datos ocurre la página actual no se mueve (no se recarga) pudiendo sin embargo actualizar cualquier contenido de ella si fuera preciso con lo que trae Ajax desde el servidor. No sé si me explico. Para tu caso lo mejor sería Ajax,

Comment: Prueba [este código pulsando sobre **`Run - F9`**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/6fju-td04). Ahí el formulario no se mueve, solamente sus input son llenados con datos distintos traídos cada vez del servidor según el id indicado. Si pides el id `1` te llena el formulario con los datos de la persona 1, si el id `2` con los de la persona 2, etc. Sin embrago la página no se recarga en ningún momento, los datos son llevados y traídos por un archivo auxiliar que no es el actual. Tan simple como eso es la magia de Ajax.

Comment: Sé que ajax no recarga la página, lo he usado en otras ocasiones para sacar algún select y alguna cosa mas. Pero mi duda es si tengo ajax y php se recargará si o si,no? por eso te preguntaba si al venir de recargar php se perdería. Lo suyo es hacerlo entero con Ajax? Es que hay varias cosas en la misma página, como lo de borrar los registros

Comment: Lo acabo de resolver. Hay que poner cual está checkeado de los radio button que tenía para elegir, fecha o rango, antes de darle el valor

//fecha hoy
            $('#fecha').prop('checked', true);
            $('#selfecha').val("<?php echo $fechahoy; ?>");